# Connection to MongoDB 2.6.3 using 3.0.0 driver from Java (eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, mongodb

My simple program to connect to mongodb 2.6.3 using 3.0.0 driver fails with
"Command failed with error 59: 'no such cmd: saslStart' on server ...."

Any insight is much appreciated.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(MY_TEST_DATABASE_USER, MY_TEST_DATABASE, MY_TEST_DATABASE_PWD);
    // MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createScramSha1Credential(MY_TEST_DATABASE_USER, MY_TEST_DATABASE, MY_TEST_DATABASE_PWD); // this failed as well
    try (MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress(DB_SERVER_2_6_3, DB_PORT), Arrays.asList(credential))) {

        MongoDatabase mdb = mongoClient.getDatabase(MY_TEST_DATABASE);

        MongoCollection<Document> coll = mdb.getCollection(MY_TEST_COLLECTION);

        if (coll != null) {
            System.out.println(coll.find().first());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out by trial and error. (disappointed with mongo online support/docs on this issue)
Used "admin" database when creating credentials. Figured this out by looking at the connection settings in my Robomongo client.

```
MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(MY_TEST_DATABASE_USER, "admin", MY_TEST_DATABASE_PWD);
```